# Server Oauth 2.0 with Android application

Tags: java, api, oauth-2.0, token

I have a server oauth 2.0 and I would like connect my android application (Java android) with my server to get access token and use the services of my API.

I think that I must use AccountManager ?
I looked at this site: http://blog.udinic.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/